# How to use the Python GTK3 (gi.repository) gdk_event_get_scroll_deltas() method

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm attempting to port a Python program from GTK2 to GTK3.

I understand the use of GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK but can find no reference to an implementation of [gdk_event_get_scroll_deltas()](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.4/gdk3-Events.html#gdk-event-get-scroll-deltas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be in Gdk.Event.get_scroll_deltas.  If not, you should check your library version.

```
eric@hum:():~$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jun 25 2012, 23:10:56) 
[GCC 4.7.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gi.repository import Gdk
>>> "get_scroll_deltas" in dir(Gdk.Event)
True
```